# Compact Hausdorff spaces as a cocompletion of profinite sets

Tags: ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology

It is well-known that the category CH of compact Hausdorff spaces has a strong categorical flavor (e.g. [Properties of the category of compact Hausdorff spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382348/properties-of-the-category-of-compact-hausdorff-spaces), which includes Manes' theorem asserting that CH is the category of algebras over the ultrafilter monad.

On the other hand CH contains the full subcategory ProFin of profinite spaces, which in turn admits a purely categorical interpretation as the Pro-completion of the category of finite sets.

Is there a way in which CH arises by ProFin by freely adding some sort of colimits?

Comment: The ultrafilter monad can also be defined “purely categorically theoretically”. Look up codensity monads.

Comment: @Zhen Lin: Thanks, I am aware of Leinster's work. However that does not seem (?) to answer my question above.

Comment: See [this earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/439402). I intend to expand my comments to an answer but I've been quite busy lately. In short, the category of compact Hausdorff spaces is the free $\aleph_1$-cofiltered completion of the category of compact metrizable spaces (or closed subsets of $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ if you need a *small* rather than just essentially small category when you take a completion). This is best viewed under Gelfand duality - a commutative unital C$^*$-algebra is an $\aleph_1$-filtered colimit of separable commutative unital C$^*$-algebras.

Comment: I think this is due to J. W. Negrepontis/J. W. Pelletier (the same person) [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(71)90105-0) with a later axiomatization with Rosický as a coauthor [here](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01196099).

Comment: You're never going to get all compact Hausdorff spaces as a *limit* of finite spaces because Stone spaces are closed under limits (because the product of Stone spaces is Stone and a closed subspace of a Stone space is Stone).

Comment: @Jakob Your specific question is a lot narrower than the title question… but in some sense the answer must be yes, if the category of compact Hausdorff spaces can be embedded in some category of sheaves over profinite sets. The colimits would not be _free_ (corresponding to the non-trivial Grothendieck topology) and it is not obvious to me what diagram shapes would be needed.

Comment: Thank you, @Robert Furber and Zhen Lin for your comments. I tweaked the title to fit better.  My motivation is: is known that [0,1] is a quotient of the profinite space $\{0, 1\}^\mathbb N$ modulo the relation identifying a chain of 1's in such a sequence with 0. More generally, it is known that a comp. Hausdorff space is a quotient of a profinite space by a profinite equivalence relation. If I'm not missing anything this seems to suggest an essentially surjective functor from the free cocompletion of ProFin by Delta-indexed colimits to CH.

Comment: @Robert Furber: note that the question is not about presenting CH-spaces as a limit of ProFin (=Stone) spaces, but rather as colimits.

Comment: @ZhenLin Maybe one could try extremally disconnected compact Hausdorff spaces (which are particular profinite spaces) as a (non-small) site, given that every compact Hausdorff space is a (canonical) quotient of an extremally disconnected one (its Gleason cover)? I am not sure though if one would not get some extra stuff besides "ordinary" compact Hausdorff spaces - I believe this is what the whole condensed mathematics is about...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე : compact Hausdorff spaces indeed embed fully faithfully in the free sifted-cocompletion of extremally disconnected sets, which is the category of condensed sets.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I think you have a good answer to add.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე : it is a partial answer, if Jakob wants me to write it out as an answer, I'll be happy to but I don't believe it is fully satisfactory

Comment: @MaximeRamzi OK. Do you know if that embedding has a left adjoint?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  it does, because the category of compact Hausdorff spaces has all colimits (and the embedding is given by a restricted Yoneda embedding)

Comment: Aha, so although the reflector is most likely not pullback preserving, still at least in principle one might determine what kind of "quotient" of the free sifted-cocompletion gives compact Hausdorff spaces, right? That is, which mоrphisms become inverted. Or has it been already computed by somebody?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi: your remark sounds interesting. Does it imply something about the full faithfulness of the free cocompletion of ProFin under Delta^op-indexed colimits mapping to CHaus?